# python match image tags from large content string using regular expressions

Tags: python, django

am really a noob with regular expressions, I tried to do this on my own but I couldn't understand from the manuals how to approach it. Am trying to find all img tags of a given content, I wrote the below but its returning None

```
            content = i.content[0].value
            prog = re.compile(r'^<img')
            result = prog.match(content)
            print result
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Multipurpose solution:

```
image_re = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<img_tag><img)\s+    #tag starts
    [^>]*?                  #other attributes
    src=                    #start of src attribute
    (?P<quote>["''])?       #optional open quote
    (?P<image>[^"'>]+)      #image file name
    (?(quote)(?P=quote))    #close quote
    [^>]*?                  #other attributes
    >                       #end of tag
    """, re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE) #re.VERBOSE allows to define regex in readable format with comments

image_tags = []
for match in image_re.finditer(content):
    image_tags.append(match.group("img_tag"))

#print found image_tags
for image_tag in image_tags:
    print image_tag
```

As you can see in regex definition, it contains

```
(?P<group_name>regex)
```

It allows you to access found groups by `group_name`, and not by number. It is for readability. So, if you want to show all `src` attributes of `img` tags, then just write:

```
for match in image_re.finditer(content):
    image_tags.append(match.group("image"))
```

After this image_tags list will contain src of image tags.

Also, if you need to parse html, then there are instruments that were designed exactly for such purposes. For example it is [lxml](http://lxml.de/), that use [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expressions.

Comment: hi stalk, your solution works 100% i just test it and I think with the explanation put, am starting to understand a little. I just have a question about the returned value, when i print image_tags list, it contains "<img" how can i make sure it returned the full image tag?

Comment: To get full image tag surround full regex expression with brackets, like so: image_re = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<img_full_tag>
    (?P<img_tag><img)\s+    #tag stargs
    [^>]*?                  #other attributes
    src=                    #start of src attribute
    (?P<quote>["''])?       #optional open quote
    (?P<image>[^"'>]+)      #image file name
    (?(quote)(?P=quote))    #close quote
    [^>]*?                  #other attributes
    >)                      #end of tag
    """, re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)   And use image_tags.append(match.group("img_full_tag"))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python but assuming it uses normal Perl compatible regular expressions...

You probably want to look for "<img[^>]+>" which is: "<img", followed by anything that is not ">", followed by ">". Each match should give you a complete image tag.